# Custom NSControl

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscell, nscontrol

I'm trying to create my own NSControl by creating xib file and associate it with its .h and .m files

My control is a subclass of NSControl and it contains NSStepper and NSTextfield, the reason I use the NSControl superclass is that I want my control to be Actionable later from the IB.

I would like my control to use the Superclass (NSControl) values like doubleValue etc … However when I set a value it is always 0 and I think it is due to the fact that its cell is nil

My control have two cells: NSTextFieldCell and NSStepperCell, however in the NSControl there is only option to put one cell

How can I solve this issue?

Am I missing something?

Thanks